# Why is my laravel installer version still 2.1.0?

Tags: laravel

When it i first time installed laravel using

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

it shows the version of 2.1.0 not the latest version?

How to fix this problem? i know i can install specific laravel version with

```
`composer create-project laravel/laravel="6.0.*" appName`
```

It's annoying cause in the terminal it still shows the version of 2.1.0

Comment: 2.1.0 _is_ the latest version of the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of `Laravel` installer as of the moment is `2.1.0`. Just take note that it is not same with the `Laravel` framework that will be installed. They're two separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

hat it is not same with the Laravel framework

```
laravel -V
```

it gives you laravel installer version

```
php artisan --version
```

You get laravel framework version.For you then show it laravel framework 6.

Comment: And therefore that it is version 6 the way of doing php artisan make:auth is no more in laravel framework 6 right?

Comment: yes..For this First Install the laravel/ui Composer package with the following command:    composer require laravel/ui    then  php artisan ui vue --auth    Laravel 6 has moved the Auth Scaffolding into a seperate package.  in laravel doc you get all this